# Python wrap component constructor with method and keep argument completion

Tags: python, pycharm, python-decorators

Let's say I have a component object, e.g. Route.

```
class Route:
    def __init__(self, url='localhost', port=80)
        ...
```

And I want to provide a routing manager class, similar to what Flask does with `@app.route`, so I can create and keep track of Routes:

```
class Router:
    def route(self, *args, **kwargs):
        route = Route(*args, **kwargs)
        self.routes.append(route)
```

Is there an easy way to make the `Router.route` method have argument completion and/or documentation automatically reflecting `Route.__init__`?

I tried to use `functools.wraps`, but it had no immediate effect. Maybe I used it wrong?

```
class Router:
    @wraps(Route.__init__)
    def route(self, *args, **kwargs):
        route = Route(*args, **kwargs)
        self.routes.append(route)
```

**EDIT**: I'm using Python 3.6 with the newest PyCharm (2016.3.2).

Comment: What IDE do you want to work your completion in? What Python version are you using? Old APIs look directly into the code object; there is no way to trick them. Newer code uses advanced protocols.

Comment: I was hoping for a one-size-fits-all solution, but I updated the question with my setup. A specific solution is better than no solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do

```
import inspect
print(inspect.signature(Route.route))
print(help(Route.route))
```

you'll see that `functools.wraps` actually does work. However, it appears that PyCharm is unaware of the meaning of functools.wraps. I suggest to report this as a bug to [JetBrains](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY).

Comment: Have you reproduced it? I wanna make sure before reporting.

Comment: Yes, I did. PyCharm does not recognize functools.wraps in that manner.

Comment: There is now a PyCharm bug [PY-23067](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-23067#tab=Comments&u=1492615536736) requesting this functionality. 
 @VillasV - If you want the functionality, vote for it.