# why isn't functools.wraps preserving intellisense?

Tags: python, decorator, wrapper, functools

python 3.12 pycharm pro 2023.2.2

i have this (stripped down) code where i check if an input is an `id` or `serial`, and then convert as necessary. with the decorator in place pycharm does not warn me that `get_id` fails to pass `df` to `serial_to_id`. i thought functools.wraps was supposed to solve this exact issue? if i comment out the decorator i get the desired squiggly red line

```
def a_decorator(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

def an_id(id_or_serial):
    return len(id_or_serial) == 4

@a_decorator
def serial_to_id(serial, df):
    return convert(df=df, value=serial)

def get_id(id_or_serial):
    return id_or_serial if an_id(id_or_serial) else serial_to_id(id_or_serial)
```

Comment: Looks like an open issue with PyCharm: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-62760/Support-functools.wraps

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python wrap component constructor with method and keep argument completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42738602/python-wrap-component-constructor-with-method-and-keep-argument-completion)

Comment: thankyou!! didn't even occur to me that it was something other than my partial-at-best-understanding of what i'm doing!

Comment: In this case, it's not you, it's the IDE :)

Comment: sadly, it looks like this issue was raised in - checks stone tablet - 2016. so i can only assume they have no intention of addressing it. i love pycharm. first time i've been sorely disappointed. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-23067/Pycharm-not-picking-function-metadata-from-functools.wraps-with-methods

Comment: What do I know, but a JetBrains employee created that PY-62760 ticket just 4 weeks ago. (The underlying issues it links to are indeed older, but PY-48338 and PY-23067 were updated 3 days ago.)

Comment: looking at [decohints](https://github.com/gri-gus/decohints) it looks like can just add `    wrapper: func` to the decorator before returning the wrapper. nope. it adds the params to suggestions, but still no squiggly-line warning